# Who is the defense attorney in Parke Godwin's 'The Snake Oil Wars'?

Tags: character-identification, inspiration

The prosecutor is easy to unmask, but what's the real-world identity of Lance Candor's attorney? Clues from the text point to a European dark age religious figure, beyond that I'm lost.

Comment: Fun fact: [Snake oil works](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=snake-oil-salesmen-knew-something)

Comment: It's been years since I've read this book...maybe there is an e-version available for a good price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accoring to [this Usenet post](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Rec/rec.arts.sf.written/2011-09/msg01450.html), Peter Helm is [this real world figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_calvin).